# How to split large string on single character that is also part of the data

Tags: python

I have a array that contains a single string. Inside of the array is data in a format such as:

```
key=value&key=value&key=value&key=value&key=value.....
```

I can split on the character `&` and everything is good. But sometimes one of the values will contain one or more `&`. I am not sure how to account for that since it will break up the value.

So if the value contained something like

```
asdfasdf&asdfasdf&asdfasdf&asdfasfd&asfd
```

Then it would split that up when I really want that to just be a single value.

EDIT:

Sample Input:

```
['apple=true&orange=true&cherry=true&dog=apple&cherry&orange']
```

Expected Output:

```
apple=true
orange=true
cherry=true
dog=apple&cherry&orange
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I don't have anything. I am not sure how I would do this.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but do you have control over what produces the key-value pairs? If it's a URL query, then those "`&`" part of the values should have been encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values (or the names) cannot contain the equal sign, you can do this:

```
a = "a=1&b=2&3&4&c=5&d=6&e=7&8"

s = a.split("=")
s[-1] = s[-1] + "&"
names = [i.rpartition('&')[2] for i in s[:-1]]
vals = [i.rpartition('&')[0] for i in s[1:]]

print(zip(names, vals))
```

The output you will get is going to be:

```
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2&3&4'), ('c', '5'), ('d', '6'), ('e', '7&8')]
```

It's worth mentioning that a scheme that forces you to make a distinction between the `&` characters as separators or parts of the data is not a good scheme. Quoting of values is a good solution, and HTTP GET requests should/would escape the `&`s in the request.

Comment: print(list(zip(names, vals)))